# How to make sure a user is entering a specific string?

Tags: java, string, encryption, equality, negation

I'm trying to ask a user whether they want to encrypt or decrypt a message, and I know that I need to use `userInput.equals("encrypt")`, but i want to use a while loop with !=.

```
    while(userInput.!equals("encrypt") || userInput.!equals("decrypt")){
        System.out.println("Please try again. Check spelling, and that you typed either 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.);
        userInput = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    }
```

and I dont know the syntax for the `userInput.!equal("x")`. (Obviously, what I put is not right).

Comment: put the exclamation mark in front of the method call `while(!userInput.equal("encrypt") || !userInput.equal("decrypt"))`, so the output gets inverted

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It works. I can't accept an answer for another couple minutes tho

Comment: Wait.  It will ALWAYS either not equal "encrypt" or not equal "decrypt".  Shouldn't that be a `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the `while loop` condition to this:

```
while(!userInput.equals("encrypt") && !userInput.equals("decrypt"))
```

also, if you want to ignore case:

```
while(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt"))
```

Comment: But it needs to be `&&` instead of `||`.